# How to capture the word with space around without capturing the space?

Tags: python, regex

I've got a string like this `s = "Hello this is Helloworld #helloworld #hiworld #nihaoworld "` The idea is to catch all the hashtag however the hashtag needs to have a boundary around. e.g. if something like `"Hello this is helloworld#helloworld"`won't be captured.

I want to generate the following result as `["#helloworld","#hiworld","nihaoworld"]`
I've got the following python code

```
import re
print re.findall('(?:^|\s+)(#[a-z]{1,})(?:\s+|$)', s)
```

The result I got is `["#helloworld","#nihaoworld"]` with the middle word missing

Comment: why not just `s.strip().split()`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Tbh this is one of my assignments and the instruction here is to avoid tokenisation. I've tried multiple other methods but all not working

Comment: Have you considered `print (re.findall('(#[a-z]+)', s))`? That seems to work.

Comment: Your regex just looks fine for the job. Did you double check input value?

Comment: @PJProudhon his regex will not match consecutive hashtags, because he doesn't check for the `\s` character belonging to two groups, he treats them as though there should be 2 `\s` characters.

Comment: My bad, I should have seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need a regular expression for this, you can just use:

`s.strip().split()`

However, if you do want to use a regex, you could just use [`(?:^|\s)(#\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/MDr0IW/1):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = " #helloworld #hiworld #nihaoworld "
>>> re.findall(r'(?:^|\s)(#\w+)', s)
['#helloworld', '#hiworld', '#nihaoworld']
```

**Explanation**

- Non-capturing group `(?:^|\s)`

  - 1st Alternative `^`

    - `^` asserts position at start of the string
  - 2nd Alternative `\s`

    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- 1st Capturing Group `(#\w+)`

  - `#` matches the character `#` literally (case sensitive)
  - `\w+` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
  - `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Comment: Hi Chris thanks for your answer! I've just edited my question a little bit

Comment: @YiyueWang updated my answer, let me know if that works for you